# How to make a map of generic consumers interfaces with type contravariance parameters?

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I'm trying to implement a SOLID approach to my app in Android. I follow [this post](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2011/meanwhile-on-the-query-side-of-my-architecture/) to develop an generic interface to implement in a Adapter class to select the Auth Provider of the user. In my constructor, I require a map with the possibles implementations to the multiples auth providers (Facebook, Google, etc.), but when I build the map, the compiler complains about the "incompatible types" of the objects.

I tried to introduce some covariance and contravariance operators in the generic interfaces, and used the "star projection" to the map, but the compiler fails when compose the map or when I call to the function of the interface in my implementations.

This is the interface that extends the Parameters Objects to the implementations

```
interface IQuery<TResult>
```

This is an example of a Parameter Object

```
data class FacebookLoginEvent (
        val requestCode: Int,
        val resultCode: Int,
        val data: Intent?
): IQuery<String>
```

And this is the interface for the implementations for the Auth services

```
interface IQueryService<TQuery: IQuery<TResult>, TResult> {
    fun execute(query: TQuery): TResult
}
```

An example of a Auth Provider implementation

```
class FacebookSignInFlow(): IQueryService<FacebookLoginEvent, String> {
    override fun execute(query: FacebookLoginEvent): String {
        // Do something with the event
    }
}
```

The composite class with an enumerator to select the provider that makes the authentication

```
class CredentialSignInFlow(
        private val signInFlowProviders: Map<
                CredentialSignInFlowProvider,
                IQueryService<IQuery<String>, String>
        >
) {
    fun signIn(provider: CredentialSignInFlowProvider, query: IQuery<String>){
        signInFlowProviders.getValue(provider).execute(query)
    }
}

enum class CredentialSignInFlowProvider{
    FacebookProvider,
    GoogleSilentProvider,
    GoogleProvider
}
```

When I send the map, the compiler says that

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Map<CredentialSignInFlowProvider, FacebookSignInFlow> but Map<CredentialSignInFlowProvider, IQueryService<IQuery<String>, String>> was expected
```

Here's the code to compose the object graph

```
CredentialSignInFlow(mapOf(
    CredentialSignInFlowProvider.FacebookProvider to FacebookSignInFlow()
))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `CredentialSignInFlow` expects exactly `Map<CredentialSignInFlowProvider, IQueryService<IQuery<String>, String>>` class and doesn't apply any `IQuery<String>` inheritors into service generic.

I can see here only one solution - make `CredentialSignInFlow` generic too.

```
class CredentialSignInFlow<T : IQuery<String>>(
        private val signInFlowProviders: Map<
                CredentialSignInFlowProvider,
                IQueryService<T, String>
                >
) {
    fun signIn(provider: CredentialSignInFlowProvider, query: T){
        signInFlowProviders.getValue(provider).execute(query)
    }
}
```